# Magento234 code optimization

Tags: magento2, speedoptimization, magento234, website-speed

For optimize already minify CSS, js. Merged CSS and js. But still not achieve as much exact results.

Gtmatrix always display F scored.

How to optimize the code and
increased site load time?

Comment: Check your server Resource also network resource for get high performance.

Answer (score 1):

Dont Merge JS this is no more recommended. With Http2 the benefits of merge do not compensate for the increase in JS payload due to merge JS.

Recommended :

1. Advance JS Bundle
2. Disable modules.
3. Remove JS that are not actually used in front end but are a part of module to be used.
4. Varnish is a must have.
5. Elastic search
6. Upgrade to 2.4.x
7. Responsive images
8. webP images
9. Look for TBT code due to JS and optimize or replace by css
10. Differ JS or add async.
11. replace moment.js with other lib if all features not needed which is a true in most cases.
12. Deliver images as per resolution suing picture tag.
13. Critical css
14. Reduce number of fonts used.
15. Minimise JS above fold.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the Advanced JavaScript bundling recommendations by Adobe: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/performance-best-practices/advanced-js-bundling.html

Magepack might also be worth checking out, depending on your theme it may or may not help. We had mixed results in the past: https://github.com/magesuite/magepack

If you can, rebuild your theme on top of Hyvä, this should give you the best results as it focuses fully on building fast frontends with state of the art technology: https://hyva.io/hyva-themes-license.html